# How to disable click on highlighted day fullcalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have got a booking calendar which fetches events from a database table and highlights the specific dates that have events on, but how do I disable the click event for dates that have a booking.

For each day that is available I have a click event which opens a modal window with a booking form but don't want this to happen with the ones that have bookings.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: "inc/fetch-bookings.php",
eventAfterAllRender : function(view) {

    //Loop through all event to set the highlight and onclick url
    $(".fc-event-container").each(function(){

    // Get this day of the week number
    var weekDayIndex = $(this).index();
    // Get the calendar row
    var row = $(this).closest(".fc-row");
    // Get this date
    var date = row.find(".fc-day-top").eq(weekDayIndex).attr("data-date");
    // Add highlight and data-date
    row.find(".fc-day").eq(weekDayIndex)
        .addClass("highlight");
    });
    
},
selectOverlap: function(event) {
        $('#modalbook').fadeOut();
            $('.modaloverlay').fadeOut();
      },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    longPressDelay: 0,
    eventLongPressDelay: 0,
    selectLongPressDelay: 0,
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    viewRender: function(currentView){
        var minDate = moment();
        if (minDate >= currentView.start && minDate <= currentView.end) {
            $(".fc-prev-button").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".fc-prev-button").show();
        }
    },
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    selectAllow: function(info) {
        if (info.start.isBefore(moment().add(-1, 'days'))) {
            return false; return true;
        }
    },
    select: function(date) {
        var timestamp = Number(new Date());
        var date = date.format();
        $("span.bookingdate").text(date);
        $('#bookingdate').val(date);

        $('#modalbook').fadeIn(600);
        $('.modaloverlay').fadeIn(600);
        $('body').addClass('modalopn');
    },
});
```

[image: fullcalendar.js]

Thanks for you help.

My code has been updated above which has been tested where days have events on them then the date won't be selectable, the answer was to use the fullcalendar.js 'selectOverlap' function so it becomes unselectable.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this with css, add a css class to the booked dates and put this styling for that class:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

If you want to add a class from JavaScript use:

Javascript:

```
const bookedDates = document.querySelectorAll('.fc-day-top');

bookedDates.forEach(function (bookedDate) {
    bookedDate.classList.add('bookedDate');
});
```

CSS:

```
.bookedDate {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5mknuy8a/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where in my code would I add this line?

Comment: in your css file, first inspect the booked dates and look if it has a unique class. and add the code to that class.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ebv4n1t/ look here. I create an example. if you remove `pointer-events` you can click on the item.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working it still opens a modal, I have added the following (row.find(".fc-day-top span").eq(weekDayIndex).addClass('booked');) and applied the CSS for pointer events.

Comment: you don't need to add them with jQuery, just add it in the css like the example I give.

Comment: I did this with CSS and pointer events get disabled, but I need to add a class to know which days have bookings and add the class name to CSS with pointer event doesn't work.

Comment: why do you not use JavaScript instead of jQuery? See my updated answer. https://jsfiddle.net/5mknuy8a/2/

Comment: Thank for your advise and help with my question. Fullcalendar.js when you are using selectable and select function the pointer events dont work. I have updated my question above on how I achieved this using the Fullcalendar.js 'selectOverlap'.